# Write a function that takes a list of words and returns the longest word and length of the longest one

Tags: python

The full question is "Write a function find_longest_word() that takes a list of words and 
returns the longest word and length of the longest one. You should also write a test function 
that will request the users for a list of words and print the longest word and its length."

I wrote this code and it works. I just need to figure out how i can add a function into this code to to what I am told in the question.

```
def main():
    text = input("Please input a list of words to evaluate: ")

    longest = 0

    for words in text.split():
        if len(words) > longest:
            longest = len(words)
            longest_word = words

    print("The longest word is", longest_word, "with length", len(longest_word))

main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply move the logic, into a function, like this

```
def find_longest_word(text):
    for words in text.split():
        if len(words) > longest:
            longest = len(words)
            longest_word = words
    return longest_word, len(longest_word)

def main():
    input_string = input("Please input a list of words to evaluate: ")
    longest_word = find_longest_word(input_string)
    print("The longest word is", longest_word, "with length", len(longest_word))
```

The actual problem, you are trying to solve can be solved like this

```
def find_longest_word(text):
    longest_word = max(text.split(), key = len)
    return longest_word, len(longest_word)
```

**Note:** Instead of printing the result in the `find_longest_word` function, we are returning the `longest_word` from it, so that the function does only what it is supposed to do. Now, as the name suggests, it just finds the longest word.

Comment: you should move the print back into main

Comment: @mhlester no he shouldn't (it's more generic this way - it can be used/called from other places in the code as well). +1

Comment: the prompt says to write a test function that *requests* and *prints* the result. `find_longest_word` needs to *return* the longest word and its length

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `longest_word = words`, but without your answer, It was not possible to answer this exercise ...., so thanks!

```
def main ():
    text = input("Please input a List of words to evaluate: ")

    longest = 0

    for words in text.split():
           if len(words) > longest:
                  longest = len(words)
    print ("The longest word is", words, "with lenght", longest)


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This exercise with a short codec....

```
def main():
    a = sorted(input("Please input a list of words to evaluate: ").split(), key=len) [-1]
    print ("You longe word ", str(a), " have this", str(len(a)), "lenghts")

main()
```

Comment: try your solution for string: `'vfsdafs xx sssssssssss ddddd'` does it work correctly?

Comment: and why come first ddddd and second sssssssssss ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_longest_word(words_list):  
    word_len = []  
    for n in words_list:  
        word_len.append((len(n), n))  
    word_len.sort()  
    return word_len[-1][1]  

print(find_longest_word(["hasta ", "lavista", "baby"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a python program to read a list of words and return the length of the longest one:

```
list_words = ["PHP", "Exercises", "Backend"]<br/>
s = [(len(word),word) for word in list_words] <br/>
s.sort() <br/>
print('Longest String in list is ',s[-1][1]) <br/>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
numberOfWordsInList = int(input("Enter number of words to be List: "))

def longestWordInList(numberOfWordsInListt):
    createdList = [input("Enter any word: ") for i in range(numberOfWordsInList)]    
    lengthOfItems = [(len(items), items) for items in createdList]
    return max(lengthOfItems)

print(longestWordInList(numberOfWordsInList))
```